# Write R package in Julia?

Tags: r, julia, rcpp

Is it possible to develop a set of functions in [julia](/questions/tagged/julia) (e.g. a specialised optimization algorithm), "compile" it and then use this code from [r](/questions/tagged/r) standalone, i.e. without needing a `julia` installation?

- In other words, is it possible to use Julia as we can already use `Cpp`?
- Or there plans to support this kind of workflow in the nearer future?

I am aware of the `Julia` and `JuliaCall` packages, but I think they were designt for a different kind of workflow.

Comment: I think the underlying question here is if there's a way to compile julia code into a persistent binary or library that can be used without a julia installation, regardless of using it from R or something else. I'm not a julia user (yet), but I found https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl, which does discuss making a shared library. From there, it would be an interesting test to link to that library in R ... if it's a "normal library", this should be feasible.

Comment: Julia uses the C ABI, so it should be able to be linked like any other normal library. But these tools are definitely in their infancy right now, with more support being developed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PackageCompiler.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl) to generate a shared library which you can call from R or C easily enough (instructions in their readme). The binaries are huge and often still have long start-up times, but there is ongoing, funded work on static compiling in Julia, so this will plausibly get better over the next year or so.